# Using directives in real life angular app, are directives with controllers a right approach?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know that this topic was discussed many times but I'm still not quite sure if I'm doing things right..

Many on-line resources embrace directives as a building blocks of the angular applications, in the same time many resources emphasize re-usability of the components. Anyway from my experience when I build typical app, there is not much things to re-use, usually each component has single role and it is used in the single place. As I understand angular, one of the main concepts is to provide semantic DOM, and in order to achieve that we can use directives. So when I build an angular app usually I create a set of directives and combine them in the views.

In my apps in the most cases all the DOM manipulation can be done using the build in directives. Most of my directives has a template and a controller, I do not need to use link function. In most of the resources in the internet I can read that I should use link function when creating directives. But this seems to be far more complicated code... . What is the benefit of the link function if I don't need any fancy DOM manipulations that are beyond build-in directives ?

tldr; I build my apps using directives with controllers and put them into views, is this a right approach ?

Comment: a quick thing you might think first is whether you need to public your API, if yes use controller, if no use link.

Comment: hi @elaijuh, yes I read that. I don't need public API. The thing is why ? When I use controller, my code is way less complicated. What is the benefit of the link function if I do not need any fancy DOM manipulations that are beyond build in directives ?

Comment: controller itself is a $provide kept in `cacheProvider` which means it can be injected anywhere. link function cannot be injected and only fit for action on the specific directive. another thing to be considered is if the controller only does business for this specific directive, try not to let this design happen.

Comment: The $provider thing seems to be only a theoretical problem, i do not see much consequences of that.. Regarding the business logic - as I said before, I do not do any DOM manipulations that are beyond the build in directives. But I do see benefits from having html templates with semantic DOM (by using build in directives). Maybe I do not fully understand the angular concepts, and I should just stick to the views instead of directives ?

Comment: can you clarify more on what you are building now? and your confusion is to put stuff in link or controller right?

Comment: Why is your code less complicated when you use a controller instead of a link function?

Comment: Hi, sorry for ambiguity, English is not my mother tongue. This is just a general question, not a particular case. I'm trying to find the best way of structuring the angular apps. Right now I use directives as a building blocks of my apps (for example: I have a list of customers - I create a directive for that). In my directives I use build in directives like ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-click etc. and combine them with controller embedded in the directive. But with the link function, things get more complicated. So question is why to compicate ?

Comment: hi @zeroflagL, good question, I think I do not fully understand, what happens in the link function. can I just put my controllers code into a link function ? I was convinced that link function is the place for DOM manipulation, but I do not do any.... and when you use link you do not use ng-repeat but angular.foreach...

Comment: Even if it's a general question an example would be helpful to discuss specific points, in particular what gives you the impression that it's more complicated. Yes, the link function is the right place for dealing with the DOM. There seems to be a trend towards extensively using controllers in directives and it has its advantages.

Comment: Sorry, will try to find something, but for now lets say that we have a "customer list" directive, it just displays a list of customers, when you click on the name, app switches to Details state. In my opinion DOM is more semantic if you use ng-click instead of elem.bind('click... and ng-repeat insted of angluar.forEach.

Comment: I found this resource: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers, this directives are called “child views”. what do you think about this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing in Angular over a year now on an enterprise level application and my team has gone by a standard of creating directives if you are using that same element more than once. It saves time, saves the DOM trouble, and makes it easy to create separate, testable pieces of code.

We've created directives for many listing items that use ng-repeat. Pretty much every ng-repeat we have is iterating over a directive to create true isolate scope in our elements' functionality. It's one of the most powerful features in AngularJS when done right and conforms to the standards of Object Oriented Programming where you can really make your applications use abstraction to the finest degree. [Here's a wiki link on abstraction.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29)